# Launch a script from GUI and see the commands

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to circumvent the absence of desktop shortcuts in Gnome by running the script from GUI through an explicitly launched instance of `konsole`:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh 

set -x
konsole --hold -e echo test
```

When I test this in terminal, the command is printed in the window I launched the script **from**:

```
[zorath@localhost sav]$  ./test.sh 
+ konsole --hold -e echo test
```

When I launch it from GUI, the '+' line is swallowed. Is there a trick to have the command printed in the new window, along with the script output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running `echo test` in the shell started by `konsole`, start a shell with tracing turned on, and run `echo test` in *that*:

```
konsole --hold -e sh -x -c 'echo test'
```

Depending on how `konsole` handles the argument to `-e` (I don't have `konsole` installed to test), you may have to use

```
konsole --hold -e "sh -x -c 'echo test'"
```

Comment: Looks like `konsole` handles it exactly the way you expected. Command echo is visible now. Thanks, man.